# PAPI and native events

Tags: c, papi

Is it possible to find the set of native events (CPU counter registers) that maps to a PAPI event ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If  you have papi installed, you can use papi_avail to get the native events. For example,

papi_avail -e PAPI_TOT_INS

> Event name:                   PAPI_TOT_INS
>   Event Code:                   0x80000032
>   Number of Native Events:      1
>   Short Description:           |Instr completed|
>   Long Description:            |Instructions completed|
>   Developer's Notes:           ||
>   Derived Type:                |NOT_DERIVED|
>   Postfix Processing String:   ||
>    Native Code[0]: 0x40000002 |INSTRUCTION_RETIRED|
>    Number of Register Values: 0
>    Native Event Description: |Number of instructions at retirement|

-Ganesh

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean

`papi_native_avail`

With `PAPI_event_name_to_code(...)` you can add your *event* to your *eventset* for example.

Answer (score 0):

In order to quickly see and export all available mappings from preset events to native events use `papi_decode -a` command. The output is in the CSV format. An example from my CPU:

```
pc@pc ~> papi_decode -a
name,derived,postfix,short_descr,long_descr,note,[native,...]

PAPI_L1_DCM,NOT_DERIVED,,"L1D cache misses","Level 1 data cache misses",,L1D:REPLACEMENT
PAPI_L1_ICM,NOT_DERIVED,,"L1I cache misses","Level 1 instruction cache misses",,L2_RQSTS:ALL_CODE_RD
PAPI_L2_DCM,DERIVED_SUB,,"L2D cache misses","Level 2 data cache misses",,LLC_REFERENCES,L2_RQSTS:CODE_RD_MISS
(...)
```